# Where does hsearch store data?

Tags: c, memory, hash, hashtable

I'm playing around with hash tables in C using hsearch. The question in simplest form is where in memory are the data? I thought that the hash table created by hcreate just pointed to existing memory locations, so the data was allocated by means apart from hcreate/hsearch (except for of course the hash table itself allocated by hcreate).

To test this I wrote a simple program that creates a hash table. The original data is a char array called "reply". I pick the array apart into key/value pairs using strtok_r and then create the hash table with hsearch. I perform a "look-up" with hsearch, find my key-value pair, then I clobber the original memory, and do the look-up again. I still find it. So where are the data being stored? I didn't allocate anything special. Here's some test code you can run to see what I mean. You should be able to compile this with gcc and run it.

```html
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <search.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <string.h>

/** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * store
 */
void store(char *key, char *value) {
  ENTRY e, *ep;
  e.key = key;
  e.data = value;
  ep = hsearch(e, ENTER);
  if (ep == NULL) {
    perror("hsearch");
    exit(1);
    }
  ep->data = (char *)value;
  }

/** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * fetch
 */
int fetch(char *key, char **value) {
  ENTRY e, *ep;
  e.key=key;
  ep = hsearch(e, FIND);
  if (ep) {
    *value = (char *)ep->data;
    return 1;
    }
  else
    return 0;
  }

/** ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
 * main
 */
void main( void ) {
  int i;
  char *saveptr, *token, *subtoken, *key, *value;

  // this is to simulate what a reply string looks like from my hardware...
  char reply[] = "BACKPLANE_TYPE=1 BACKPLANE_REV=3 BACKPLANE_VERSION=1.0.641 BACKPLANE_ID=002428867071B05C POWER_ID=000000AC19B4 MOD_PRESENT=3F2";

  hcreate(64);

  if ( (token = strtok_r(reply, " ", &saveptr)) != NULL ) {
    subtoken = strstr(token, "=");
    subtoken++;
    key   = strsep(&token, "=");
    store(key, subtoken);
    }

  do {
    if ((token = strtok_r(NULL, " ", &saveptr)) != NULL) {
      if ( (subtoken = strstr(token, "=")) == NULL ) break;
      subtoken++;
      if ( (key=strsep(&token, "=")) == NULL) break;
      }
    else
      break;
    store(key, subtoken);
    } while (1);

  // recall one of the key-value pairs
  if (fetch((char*)"BACKPLANE_VERSION", &value)) printf("VER = %s\n", value);

  // wipe everything out
  saveptr= subtoken= token= key= value=NULL;
  for (i=0; i<strlen(reply); i++) reply[i]='\0';

  // where is the storage?
  if (fetch((char*)"BACKPLANE_VERSION", &value)) printf("VER = %s\n", value);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Each data point to the different position of `reply[]` array.
You can add `memset(reply, 0, sizeof(reply));` before your second `fetch` and run. You'll get nothing with the second `fetch`.